# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput real time frame capturing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm trying to save each frames from a 6 sec. video I'm recording using the iPhone back camera. The frame rate for the video is 24 frames/second, and I want to save each single frame and to save each frame metadata. I think to use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to process each frame's buffer and retrive metadata with `CMGetAttachment`. 
It is computationally possible to save each single frame at 24 frames for seconds? What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just save the frames to a MOV file using AVAssetWriter? You know that works, and you can access and decrypt the frames as necessary. If you need to save data associated with each frame, you could do that separately.